# Download CSV feed for a sheet using the new Google Spreadsheet format

Tags: php, csv, google-sheets, export-to-csv, google-sheets-api

With the change to the new Spreadsheet URL format, getting a CSV feed for a Google Spreadsheet feels like a moving target. I have a CSV feed working with this URL format:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<key>/export?id=<gid>&format=csv`

However, it seems that Google is *always* returning the first sheet for this doc. Anyone know of changes to the URL scheme or something I am missing to obtain the CSV feed for the specified GID?

Thanks

Comment: This is working as intended, for spreadsheets the export to csv will only return the information in the first sheet. Here you can find the documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents

Comment: @Gerardo I am not using the official API and making requests to a public sheet. Previously, this had worked fine. I don't see any comments about public sheets in the link (unless I missed something)

Comment: What API are you using?

Comment: @Gerardo No API. Just trying to get a CSV feed of a spreadsheet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are 99% there - the actual URL is:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<key>/export?gid=<gid>&format=csv
```

In other words, you put "?id=" instead of "?gid=". With the proper URL, then you can download any sheet in the doc, not just the first.